# Not persisting Single Sign-on Session state

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I am using an `Identity Experience Framework` policy to provide a Sign-Up/Sign-In journey that is working as expected.

Now, I want to build a "Profile Edit" journey that uses the SSO Session State to redirect the authenticated user to our existing website that is configured to accept the Open ID Connect request. Once the profile has been updated, Open ID Connect would redirect them back to the original relying party.

The problem I am having is that no matter what I have tried, the Session State does not appear to be persisted.

I am using the `<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement />` and have attempted different SSO session providers referenced here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso

Is anyone aware of a way to test that B2C's SSO Session State is persisted though Application Insights? Or perhaps an example project that shows the use of the Session State Providers.

Answer (score 0):

When user triggers the "Profile Edit" journey by clicking on a link/button, the request sent to B2C includes redirect_uri parameter, where the token is posted after Profile Edit journey is completely executed. Which is why users will always be redirected based on the value of redirect_uri parameter in the request. This must match with the redirect uri registered in the application whose client ID is passed in the request. Which is why, dynamically updating this parameter won't work.

Additionally, the Session Management technical profiles are used to maintain session state with B2C to facilitate SSO and can't be used to maintain application session state.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding SingleSignOn node to RelyingParty?

```
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SuSi" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <SingleSignOn Scope="Application" />
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
  ...
</RelyingParty>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with SSO right now. What I found out is that if your URL login URL contains a `login=prompt` part, the session cookie (SSO) is always ignored.